# How do you plot learning curves for Random Forest models?

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest

Following Andrew Ng's machine learning course, I'd like to try his method of plotting learning curves (cost versus number of samples) in order to evaluate the need for additional data samples. However, with Random Forests I'm confused about how to plot a learning curve. Random Forests don't seem to have a basic cost function like, for example, linear regression so I'm not sure what exactly to use on the y axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be possible that you're confusing a few categories here.

To begin with, in machine learning, the [learning curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Learning_curve) is defined as

> Plots relating performance to experience.... Performance is the error rate or accuracy of the learning system, while experience may be the number of training examples used for learning or the number of iterations used in optimizing the system model parameters.

Both random forests and linear models can be used for regression or classification.

- For regression, the cost is usually a function of the l2 norm ([although sometimes the l1 norm](http://www.chioka.in/differences-between-l1-and-l2-as-loss-function-and-regularization/)) of the difference between the prediction and the signal.
- For classification, the cost is usually mismatch or log loss.

The point is that it's not a question of whether the underlying mechanism is a linear model or a forest. You should decide what type of problem it is, and what's the cost function. After deciding that, plotting the learning curve is just a function of the signal and the predictions.

Comment: I'm using it for classification, so I guess then the cost is either mismath or logloss? Is this what I would use for plotting a learning curve versus number of samples?

Comment: @user123959 Yes. Those would be very logical choices.

Comment: Thanks. One last thing, could you explain this comment I read on another stack overflow question (http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/78590/learning-curve-shows-decreasing-accuracy): "Please, never ever even think about looking at error on training when fitting RF (neither most other ML methods) -- as user31264 mentioned, this number is simply meaningless. If you need a training-set based approximation of error, use the OOB error." Because this was why I was thinking the same approach of plotting the cost function wasn't viable for random forests.

Comment: Yes, it's a very important and correct comment. It states that you should never evaluate a model's performance on the data used to train it. That performance means less than nothing. In the case of learning curve rates, this means that you should hold out some data, train each time on some other data (of varying sizes), and test it on the held out data. Makes sense?

Comment: But I thought the point of the learning curves was to plot the performance on both the training and testing/CV sets in order to see if there is a variance issue. I.e. If there is a big gap between training and testing set learning curves then there must be a variance issue, etc..

Answer (score 2):

You can use this function to plot learning curve of any general estimator (including random forest). Don't forget to correct the indentation.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def learning_curves(estimator, data, features, target, train_sizes, cv):
    train_sizes, train_scores, validation_scores = learning_curve(
    estimator, data[features], data[target], train_sizes = train_sizes,
    cv = cv, scoring = 'neg_mean_squared_error')
    train_scores_mean = -train_scores.mean(axis = 1)
    validation_scores_mean = -validation_scores.mean(axis = 1)

    plt.plot(train_sizes, train_scores_mean, label = 'Training error')
    plt.plot(train_sizes, validation_scores_mean, label = 'Validation error')
    plt.ylabel('MSE', fontsize = 14)
    plt.xlabel('Training set size', fontsize = 14)
    title = 'Learning curves for a ' + str(estimator).split('(')[0] + ' model'
    plt.title(title, fontsize = 18, y = 1.03)
    plt.legend()
    plt.ylim(0,40)
```

Plotting the learning curves using this function:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
plt.figure(figsize = (16,5))
model = RandomForestRegressor()
plt.subplot(1,2,i)
learning_curves(model, data, features, target, train_sizes, 5)
```